# Аналог odtphp для MS Office

Tags: ms-word, php

Есть ли какое нибудь решение типа odtphp, но только для .doc файлов. Т.е. отправка php данных в шаблон .doc файла?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде что-то есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972924/php-html-to-doc-xls-and-odf-convertor